# Using missForest in R with categorical variables

Tags: r, statistics, imputation

I am trying to use the missForest package to impute missing data into a fairly large dataset. Most of my variables are categorical with many factors. When I run missForest, it imputes decimal values and sometimes even negative values. Obviously, I'm doing something wrong. Here is my process below:

FIRST TRY: Entering predictor data directly. I got decimal values imputed into my dataset. I know that missForest only takes matrices but I'm not sure how to force it into recognizing what columns are factors. Someone on another post recommended dummy coding, so I tried that next, witht eh same results. code is below.

SECOND TRY: Dummy coding each predictor (so time consuming) and then running that.

```
homt_sub_dummy<-homt_sub[c("Psyprob.yes", "Psyprob.no","SUB2.2.0", "SUB2.2.1", "SUB2.2.2", "SUB2.2.3", "SUB2.2.4", "SUB2.2.5", "SUB2.2.6", "SUB2.2.7","Freq1.1", "Freq1.2", "Freq1.3", "Freq1.4","FRSTUSE1.0", "FRSTUSE1.1", "FRSTUSE1.2", "FRSTUSE1.3", "FRSTUSE1.4", "FRSTUSE1.5", "FRSTUSE1.6","FRSTUSE1.7", "FRSTUSE1.8", "FRSTUSE1.9", "FRSTUSE1.10", "FRSTUSE1.11","Freq2.1", "Freq2.2", "Freq2.3", "Freq2.4","AGEcont","Gender_male", "Gender_female", "Race2.0", "Race2.1", "Race2.2", "Arrests.0", "Arrests.1", "Arrests.2")]

homt_dummy_matrix<-data.matrix(homt_sub_dummy, rownames.force = NA)
homt_dummp.imp <- missForest(homt_dummy_matrix, verbose= TRUE, maxiter = 3, ntree = 20)
homt_dummy.imp.df<-as.data.frame(homt_dummp.imp$ximp)
View(homt_dummy.imp.df)
```

[This is a chunk of the data.frame i saved with the imputed values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9eJr.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated. I'm pretty new to imputation. I wanted to compare results of MICE with this but I just can't seem to get missForest to work!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `as.factor` function to transform the class of data that you want. For example

```
cleveland_t <- transform(cleveland,V2=as.factor(V2),V3 = as.factor(V3),V6 = as.factor(V6),V7=as.factor(V7),V9 = as.factor(V9),V11=as.factor(V11),V12 = as.factor(V12),V13= as.factor(V13),v14=as.factor(V14))
```

then use the `sapply` to check the class